# Subscribing to a event in a closure while iterating through a collection results in the last item subscribing to the event

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace so {

   public abstract class Feature {
      public void doIt() {
         Console.WriteLine( GetType().FullName );
      }
   }

   class A : Feature { }
   class B : Feature { }
   class C : Feature { }

   public class SSCCE {

      event EventHandler Click;

      static void Main( string[] args ) {
         SSCCE sscce = new SSCCE();
         List<Feature> features = new List<Feature>();
         features.Add( new A());
         features.Add( new B() );
         features.Add( new C() );
         foreach ( Feature feature in features ) {
            sscce.Click += ( object sender, EventArgs e ) => { feature.doIt(); };
         }
         sscce.Click.Invoke( null, null );
      }
   }
}
```

The expected result:

```
so.A
so.B
so.C
```

The observed result:

```
so.C
so.C
so.C
```

In java, the `final` keyword in front of `Feature` in the `foreach` loop allow the `feature` value to be used in the body of the action of the lambda, before `.doIt()`.

**What's the good syntax in C#?**

Comment: What version of C# are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual C# 2010, where is the compiler? What's its name?

Comment: Jon Skeet has a helpful page. Long story short, you're probably using C# 4.0 or earlier: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx  This fix wasn't introduced until C# 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last feature gets captured by your lambda (its a closure). You should create local variable to capture feature on each iteration:

```
 foreach (Feature feature in features) {
    Feature current = feature;
    sscce.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { current.doIt(); };
 }
```

I suggest you to read [Closing over the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) article at Eric Lippert's blog.

NOTE: That was fixed in last version of C#

---

To understand what happens, lets take a look what code is generated in your case (prior C# 5). Thus your lambda uses local variable, it's not enough to generate method - compiler generates private class which captures local variables used in lambda:

```
private sealed class AnonymousClass
{
    public Feature feature;

    public void AnonymousMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.feature.doIt();
    }
}
```

And your code is modified so that it uses instance of this AnonymousClass and subscribes it's AnonymousMethod to Click event:

```
using(var enumerator = ((IEnumerable<Feature>)features).GetEnumerator())
{ 
  AnonymousClass x = new AnonymousClass();

  while(enumerator.MoveNext())
  {
     x.feature = (Feature)enumerator.Current;
     sscce.Click += new EventHandler(x.AnonymousMethod);
  }
}
```

As you can see, you have subscribed AnonymousMethod of same AnonymousClass instance several times. And that instance will have feature equal to last assigned feature. Now what is changed when you copy current feature to local variable:

```
using(var enumerator = ((IEnumerable<Feature>)features).GetEnumerator())
{
  while(enumerator.MoveNext())
  {
     AnonymousClass x = new AnonymousClass();
     x.current = (Feature)enumerator.Current; // field has local variable name
     sscce.Click += new EventHandler(x.AnonymousMethod);
  }
}
```

In this case AnonymousClass instance created on each iteration, thus AnonymousMethods of different class instances (each with own feature captured) will handle Click event. Why code differs - because, as Eric says, closure (i.e. anonymous class) is closed over variables. In order to be closed over local variable in body of loop, in second case instance of anonymous class should be created inside loop.

Comment: @GrantWinney yep, was already adding that link :)

Comment: Please, can you add a link to the Microsoft version notes which explain this bug is fixed?

Comment: @Aerospace yes, that is described in section *8.8.4 The foreach statement* of C# 5.0 specification